# HTMLPurifier - adding to ignore list

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am trying to pass some XML tags (abcdef>) through htmlpurifier. Since the tags itself are not supported, I am trying to add an element first and then adding it to allowedElements. However this is not working, i'm just getting a blank page. Any ideas please on what I am doing wrong, or if there is an easier way to achieve what i am looking for.

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', "UTF-8");
$config->set('HTML', 'DefinitionID', 'pinaki-test');
$config->set('HTML', 'DefinitionRev', 3);
$config->set('Cache', 'DefinitionImpl', null); // remove this later!
$config->set('Cache', 'SerializerPath', "/var/cache/htmlpurify");
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addElement("tag1", false, 'Empty', 'Common', array());
$def->addElement("tag2", false, 'Empty', 'Common', array());
$config->set('HTML', 'AllowedElements', array("tag1", "tag2"));
```

Let know if anyone needs any other details.

**Note:** The library is working fine without adding the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should turn on error reporting; makes dev a lot easier!

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); // or E_ALL if you're feeling good
```

Fixing a bunch of errors (the "cannot edit configuration after finalization means all your configs need to be before you getHTMLDefinition; deprecated API means that you should change your config set format but is harmless), then you get a blank string. Then you need to make sure your new elements are in the allowed elements of someone else, an easy way to do this is mark them Inline. I doubt the AllowedElements attribute is what you want, because it will exclude all other elements...

```
<?php
require_once 'library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', "UTF-8");
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'pinaki-test');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 3);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // remove this later!
$config->set('Cache.SerializerPath', "/var/cache/htmlpurify");
$config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array("tag1", "tag2"));
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addElement("tag1", 'Inline', 'Empty', 'Common', array());
$def->addElement("tag2", 'Inline', 'Empty', 'Common', array());
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify('<tag1>asf');
```

Comment: I do have errors turned on. Can you please explain what you mean by "it will exclude all other elements."... i ask this since i used the $config->set('HTML.AllowedElements', array("tag1", "tag2")) without addElements() and it didnt seem to ignore other tags. The documentation also says that it is subtractive, i.e will only act as a whitelist. Am i missing something?

Comment: I disbelieve that you have errors turned on: if they were, you wouldn't be getting a blank page. Remember that display_errors AND error_reporting both control errors.

The docs are a bit confusing in that respect. What it means by subtractive is that HTML Purifier has a built in set of allowed elements, and you can't magically add support for other elements by adding it to the allowed elements. However, AllowedElements itself acts like a whitelist, so anything not on a list you give it will be excluded.

Comment: what would you suggest then as an alternate method? thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Adding the tag to whitelist is working fine for me (as mentioned in the documentation); so i am marking this as the correct answer. Do let me know if you see any issues with this approach. Thanks for the help.