# Single quotes rejected by html purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

This is related to [HTMLPurifier - adding to ignore list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290766/htmlpurifier-adding-to-ignore-list). I have added a couple tags to the whitelist. I have this code now -

```
$config->set('HTML', 'AllowedElements', array("customreport", "column", "columnseq"));

$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addElement("customreport", 'Block', 'Flow', 'Common', array());
$def->addElement("column", 'Block', 'Inline', 'Common', array());
$def->addElement("columnseq", 'Inline', 'Empty', 'Common', array('path'=>'CDATA', 'label'=>'CDATA'));
```

The problem is, if I send a html tag which has the attribute value in single-quotes, htmlpurifier changes it to double-quotes. For e.g.

`<columnseq path='test' label='tlabel' />`

It happens even on the demo site (http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php), with test string

```
<A HREF='http://www.google.com/'>XSS</A>
```

Can this behavior be over-ridden?

Comment: Why? The output is exactly equivalent to the input, so what is the problem?

Comment: There is no difference between wrapping attribute values into single or double quotes.

Comment: yes there is, can be important for inline javascript etc

Comment: @Nealv: Not if containing single and double quotes are represented by character references.

Comment: I was about to whine about standards, but it looks like [both single and double quotes are legal](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-0) for attributes in HTML5.  Hmph, I was looking forward to that rant.

Comment: i already looked up the standards.. the issue here is that the string is changed and if i am logging any such behavior (based on difference between input and output string) then this gets logged, which is a false positive which i would want to avoid. Also, why change something if it is correct?

Comment: @David Dorward - thanks for the comment. but why change from single quotes to double quotes in the first place?

Comment: @pinaki — I assume that the tool parses the HTML to a data structure and then serializes it rather then trying to edit it using a bunch of string operations.

Comment: @David - yes, i assumed the same... the problem i have (not a very big problem though), is that the input and output are not same (the quotes differ that is)... i am not sure, but i am hoping there is some way to override this behavior or even some customization extending that i can do to get what i need :)... just a hope though..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonicalization of attribute quoting to double-quotes was an intentional design decision stemming from the fact that when we construct our in-memory representation of the HTML, we only have an associative array of attribute names to values, and no information about what the original quoting style was. If you use the DOM style parser, there is no way to get that information either.

Comment: hmmm.. the design decision makes sense to me though it has created a peculiar problem on my end. Anyway, only a problem with false positives, so i guess that is okay. thanks for the answer..

Comment: While HTML Purifier tries to be as syntax preserving as is convenient, it doesn't really go beyond that. And you are probably going to get lots of false positives from users submitting not well-formed HTML. Better to look for strings traditionally associated with XSS.

Comment: Commander - what exactly do you mean by "strings traditionally associated with XSS"?? can you give an example?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the cleanup information from htmlpurifier? what i mean is, can htmlpurifier return me the information when the input contains any xss?

Comment: Strings associated with XSS are basically any type of string that might be associated with JavaScript, like javascript or <script> or onSomeEvent. You can find a big catalog of these in a Web Intrusion Detection System (try phpids, maybe?) You can get cleanup information with the experiment Core.CollectErrors option (check the docs for more details), but that doesn't necessarily equal XSS attempt.